# Confused about $A\setminus (B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In the proof for one of De Morgan's Theorems:  $A\setminus (B\cup C)=(A\setminus B)\cap (A\setminus C)$ I'm failing to follow one of the steps. If we let $x\in A\setminus (B \cup C)$ then $x\in A$ and $x\notin (B\cup C)$, all of this makes sense to me but they lose me at the next step where they rewrite this as: $x\in A$ and $(x\notin B\mbox{ and } x\notin C)$. I don't understand how they can change it from "or" to "and". I can kind of see whats happening though since if $x\in A$ and $x\notin (B\cup C)$ then I think we have $x\in A$ or $x\in (B\cup C)$.

Comment: For these types of problems, sketching a Venn diagram can help to get an idea of what you are trying to prove and how to prove it. If you have (at least a sketch) of the proof in your head, it will be much easier to follow the one on paper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x\notin(B\cup C)$ then $x\notin B \wedge x\notin C$.

If an element is not in the union of the sets, then it is not in either of sets.  So it is not in one, and it is not in the other.

---

"Xavier is not enrolled in Business *or* Chemistry," said George.

"You mean that Xavier is not in Business," said Jean, "*and* that Xavier is not in Chemistry either?"

"That is what I said," affirmed George.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ is not in the **union** of $B$ and $C$, that means that the statement "$x\in B\cup C$" is false.

That statement is equivalent to the statement "$x\in B$ **OR** $x\in C$". The statement $p$ **or** $q$ is only false if **both** $p$ and $q$ are false.

Therefore, in order for $x\in B\cup C$ to be false, both the statement $x\in B$ **and** the statement $x\in C$ must be false.

---

The logic I described is basically the most famous De Morgan's law, which states that $$(A\cup B)^c = A^c \cap B^c$$

where $A^c$ denotes the complement of $A$.